# Delete characters at specified positions

Tags: c++, string, erase

I can’t write code to delete characters. The deletion range is indicated by the user. 
**Example:**
*Hello, World!* positions *6,7*. Result - *HelloWorld!*

Code problem: *Result: Hello, rld!*
*str.erase(n, n-m + 1);*

```
int m = 0, n = 0;
string str;
cout << "Please, enter a string: ";
getline(cin, str);
cout << "Please, enter a value of start and end positions: ";
cin >> m >> n;
str.erase(n, n-m + 1);
cout << "Result: " << str << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: What is the problem with the provided code snippet?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Result: Hello, rld!

Answer (score -1):

The first argument to `erase` is the (0-based) index of the first character to be deleted. You are giving it the *1-based* index of the *last character* to be deleted.

Correct that:

```
str.erase(m-1, n-m + 1);
```